# Setup NGINX reverse proxy with SSL?

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm trying to setup a Node.js Express server with https and to do that I am using a NGINX reverse proxy. My VPS is running Ubuntu 18.04. I updated the default server configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` to this so it works with SSL (if it works):

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    listen 433 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:433 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mediaserver;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

I ran `sudo systemctl restart nginx` to restart NGINX.
But the issue is that when I go to the IP Address of my server without https, it opens up fine, but when I go to the IP Address of my server with https, it says the site can't be reached. Any suggested fixes? Thanks.

Comment: You are only routing http traffic `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;`

Comment: How do I route https traffic as well? Would I just add another proxy pass with the https link?

Comment: Also, should I be using 2 configurations for http and https or just use 1 as shown in the code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to route the traffic to https instead of http. I also added the `proxy_redirect` directive which will route any insecure requests to https.

EDIT: Also one problem that I see, is that you are listening on the wrong port. It should be `443`, not `433`. Notice that I changed `proxy_redirect` to use port 80.

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name mediaserver;

        location / {
          proxy_pass https://localhost:3000;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
          proxy_redirect http://localhost:80 https://localhost:3000;
        }
}
```

Here is a link to the associated [NGINX documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/).

Comment: This made it so the https still does not work and also so the http does not work. Any reasons why that would happen?

Comment: Thanks, now I am getting Connection not private? Why would that happen?

Comment: You need to do some of your own research. https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/connection-not-private-explained/, `This error is caused by an issue with the website's SSL certificate – it's missing, or it's expired, or it wasn't issued by a legitimate certificate authority, or the client can't access it for some other reason.` So if you are using a self-signed cert this may happen also.

Comment: Why are you using port 3000 in the first place?

Comment: Why wouldn't I?